# Short story about a witch who grows huge by absorbing people

Tags: story-identification, magic

Okay, I'd like to provide a wealth of details, but my memory is hazy...but any help would be appreciated.

I'm looking for a short story in the F/SF genre.  A man comes home to find his house destroyed and his family killed by a "witch".  He follows the tracks/path left by the huge creature.  He meets another humanoid creature during his travels, which he befriends.

He eventually finds the witch, which has grown huge by absorbing his whole town.  He manages to draw most of the people back out of the witch, reducing it in size, and it becomes a young girl, who became the witch after being teased/tormented because she was "slow".

The whole story had a rather melancholy and surreal feel to it, and I'd very much like to rediscover it.

Any help?

Comment: This story sounds familiar, but I can't quite place it at the moment. I'll give it some thought.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just leave this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation on this section of Stack Exchange yet... but your description of this story really "feels" like the (excellent) Miyazaki movie Spirited Away. Perhaps they have a common source?

Comment: You have some rep now! To the comments with you!

Comment: Haha, I am on my way thanks to you, but "comment everywhere" requires 50 rep, and alas, I am only at 11. I can only comment on my own things right now.

Comment: @evilspoons Hmm.  I can see how you might get that from my question, but definitely not.  You're thinking of NoFace, no?  (I'm a big Miyazaki fan, so I'm quite familiar with Spirited Away).  Everything from the overall feel to the plot details don't match up.  But I appreciate the try!